# Prove that $f(x) = \frac{5x^{2}}{1 + x^{2}}$ is bounded

Tags: functions, solution-verification

I have only had experience bounding functions over certain ranges of x, so I am having trouble trying to show it is true for all x. I would appreciate any guidance or tips for these types of problems as I feel  my proof is somewhat trivial and not rigorous.
*Proof.* To show that $\frac{5x^{2}}{1 + x^{2}}$ is bounded we show that there exists an $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\mid \frac{5x^{2}}{1 + x^{2}} \mid \leq M  \: \text{for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$}$$ As $|5x^{2}|$ is already bounded from above, we seek to bound $|1 + x^{2}|$ from below. Using the triangle inequality, $|1 + x^{2}| \geq |1| + |x^{2}| > |x^{2}|$. Thus, $M = |\frac{5x^{2}}{x^{2}}| = |5| = 5$ $\square$

Comment: How is $|5 x^2|$ bounded from above? Also note that $|1+x^2| = 1 + x^2 > x^2$.

Comment: How is $5x^2$ bounded from above? It is clearly unbounded. Also, the triangle inequality is $|x+y|\leq |x|+|y|$, not the other way around. (though $x^2+1$ is a sum of two nonnegative terms, so in this case there is an equality)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it's obvious to see that $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$ (non-negativity of $f$). Second, we check $f(x) < 5$ for all $x$ as well. Indeed, we have $$f(x) = \frac{5x^2}{1+x^2} < \frac{5+5x^2}{1+x^2} = 5.$$ Hence for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $0\leq f(x) < 5$ and $f$ is bounded. Q.E.D.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

Rewrite the function as
$$\frac{5x^2}{1+x^2}=5 -\frac{5}{1+x^2}.$$
Can you bound the second fraction?

Answer (score 1):

If we put $$x=\tan(t)$$
then

$$\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}=\sin^2(t)$$

and

$$\left|\frac{5x^2}{1+x^2}\right|=5\sin^2(t)\le 5$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  The limits as $x\to\pm\infty$ are both $5$.  Put this together with the fact that the continuous image of a compact set is compact.